# Create an array from hard-coded values for use in a LAMBDA function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I have recently created a `LAMBDA` function for recursive substitutions of substrings which works when using a range:

> `LAMBDA` named ReplaceArray

```
=LAMBDA(str, list, sub, IF(ROWS(list)=1, SUBSTITUTE(str,list,sub), ReplaceArray(SUBSTITUTE(str,INDEX(list,1),sub),OFFSET(list,1,0,ROWS(list)-1),"")))
```

So for example with a range of cells:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | ABBAAABACDBDADCD |
| **2** | AA |
| **3** | AB |
| **4** | AC |
| **5** | AD |

```
=ReplaceArray(A1,A2:A5,"")
```

Gives cell value "BDBDCD"

However, when I try and use an array of values, I instead generate a `SPILL` range where in this case I have four values where each of the hard-coded values have been replaced in turn.

```
=ReplaceArray(A1,{"AA","AB","AC","AD"},"")
```

Interesting, but not what I am after.

I have tried using `TRANSPOSE` on the list to no avail.

Does anyone know how would I go about being able to use a hardcoded set of strings?

Comment: How about wrapping the full thing in `CONCAT`?

Comment: and BTW with REDUCE we can shorten the whole thing and not need the name range any more: `=REDUCE(A1,{"AA","AB","AC","AD"},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"")))`

Comment: @ScottCraner The `CONCAT` doesn't perform a stepwise function over the replacements. The reduce function however works (and with ranges) and is pretty much what I need! Add as an answer and I can accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When LAMBDA was first introduced the best way to use it was in the Name Manager.  Since then there are a myriad of Helper formula that allow us to use it outside the Name Manager and make the formula simpler and easier to understand.

For example in this case we use [REDUCE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-function-42e39910-b345-45f3-84b8-0642b568b7cb#:%7E:text=Reduces%20an%20array%20to%20an,total%20value%20in%20the%20accumulator.) which steps through an array and returns a single answer.

```
=REDUCE(A1,{"AA","AB","AC","AD"},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"")))
```

[image]

This will work with Arrays or Ranges.

There are others like SCAN,BYROW, BYCOLUMN, and others that all help control how LAMBDA iterates and returns results.